# UIImageview in TableView

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitableview, ios6

I have to display image in tableview,i got all images but it does not display. Here Array contains 3 images, these images came from server. when cell for row at indexpath call it display only 3rd image that is last image 1st and 2nd row will be blank but when it scroll my tableview from bottom to top than only 1st and 2nd image displayed.

-

```
 (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    if (appDelegate.array_xml != (id)[NSNull null])
    {
        ObjMore = [appDelegate.array_xml objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //imageview
        NSString *str_img = ObjMore.iconurl;
        str_img = [str_img stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        NSLog(@"str_img: %@", str_img);

        self.imageicon = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str_img];
        NSLog(@"url %@",url);
        [[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader]cancelLoadingURL:url];
        self.imageicon.imageURL = url;
        self.imageicon.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.imageicon.tag = indexPath.row;
        self.imageicon.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:self.imageicon];

 }
       return  cell;
}
```

Please Help. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: no, i m not cancelling url loading because with image i have to display text also and i got that all three text but only having problem in image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change your code -

[[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader]cancelLoadingURL:self.imageicon.imageURL];

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to use this [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView). I've used it and it work wonders. To call this API:

```
ASyncImage *img_EventImag = alloc with frame;
NSURL *url = yourPhotoPath;
[img_EventImage loadImageFromURL:photoPath];
[self.view addSubView:img_EventImage]; // In your case you'll add in your TableViewCell.
```

It's same as using UIImageView. Easy and it does most of the things for you. AsyncImageView includes both a simple category on UIImageView for loading and displaying images asynchronously on iOS so that they do not lock up the UI, and a UIImageView subclass for more advanced features. AsyncImageView works with URLs so it can be used with either local or remote files.

Loaded/downloaded images are cached in memory and are automatically cleaned up in the event of a memory warning. The AsyncImageView operates independently of the UIImage cache, but by default any images located in the root of the application bundle will be stored in the UIImage cache instead, avoiding any duplication of cached images.

The library can also be used to load and cache images independently of a UIImageView as it provides direct access to the underlying loading and caching classes.

Answer (score 1):

You create the object AsyncImageView instead of UIImageView

Answer (score 0):

Are you refreshing the imageview or reloading the table row once you get the image ?

Also make sure you are refreshing the UI in main thread.

Comment: No, i m not refreshing the table.

Comment: Are you setting the image to imageview once you get the image from URL?

Comment: Sorry, the url will be cancelled. I just checked it.

Comment: so make sure you get the downloaded image & set it to imageview

Comment: Yes,@arun.s i found my mistake. i forgot to set frame of imageview.